# Is Google Maps locations Page for Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, google-location-services

Would like a Google Maps page that shows places I have been. Maybe either from history data or places I save. Would also like to list places I would like to visit as saved locations. And ability to show current location? Are these things possible?

New to this.. hoping to find answers to research.

Comment: I think your question is not suitable for stackoverflow: #1 A lot of questions, #2 zero code, #3 no research efforts shown, etc. Are you web developer? Do you know javascript?